# QuickBlox file attachments received without extension

Tags: android, nativescript, quickblox

I am developing a NativeScript Android app and using QuickBlox.
I can open images and audio files inside the app, but there are some issues with .pdf, Word and Excel documents.

Code written by a co-worker:

```
var attID = message.attachments[0].id
var fileSrc = ChatManager.getQB().content.publicUrl(attID) + "/" + "/download.xml?token=" + ChatManager.getSessionToken()
```

I get the URL with blob + session token, then:

```
var intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, android.net.Uri.parse(args.object.src));
intent.addCategory(android.content.Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
application.android.startActivity.startActivity(intent);
```

In this way I successfully download .pdf files, but .doc, .docx, .xls and .xlsx return without extension.
I also tried getting the URL through `privateUrl()` (without interpolating the token), with the same result.

Another not working method:

```
httpModule.request({
        url: uid,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'QuickBlox-REST-API-Version': '0.1.0',
            'QB-Token': ChatManager.getSessionToken()
        }
    }).then(res => {
        var file = res.content.toFile();

var intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         var uri = android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(file.path));
         intent.setDataAndType(uri, 'application/pdf');
         application.android.startActivity.startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, 'Apri file...'));

});
```

Any way I try, it feels like QuickBlox returns the extension on .pdf files only. Any suggestions?

---

UPDATE:

I tried opening the URL on different devices.

```
https://api.quickblox.com/blobs/[blobId]?token=[token]
```

On Chrome for Windows and iOS Safari, the file is downloaded or opened in browser correctly. On Android, it returns without extension on these browsers: Chrome e LineageOS stock browser. On Internet Samsung 7.4.00.70, it's opened in the browser correctly.

With `httpModule.request()`, I get this warning in the debug console on result:

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type [my file mime type]
```

Comment: Did you try background http plugin ?

Comment: Thanks but it seems that the plugin only handles uploads

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I am using this workaround in native code, but later I'll need to find something that works on iOS too.
I'm not marking this as an answer since it doesn't solve the problem

```
var r = new android.app.DownloadManager.Request(android.net.Uri.parse(args.object.src));
r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName.text);
r.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
r.setNotificationVisibility(android.app.DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
var dm = application.android.startActivity.getSystemService(android.content.Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
dm.enqueue(r);
```